# How can the different Closed Hashing Variations be implemented in secondary memory?

Tags: file, data-structures, filesystems

i don't really know how to put this but, aside from it being implemented in primary memory i.e. heap, how can i implement variation 1,2 or 3 or any of the variations into the secondary memory which is where we manipulate files right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your secondary memory is something with relatively slow seek times like hard disk drives, typically you want to implement a closed hash scheme based on "buckets" where buckets can be paged into main memory in their full relatively quickly. In this manner you *usually* don't have to perform expensive disk seeks for collisions or unstored keys. This isn't a particularly trivial undertaking and often one will end up using a library such as the classic [gdbm](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/) or [others](http://www.dss.ca/dx/free_databases/free_dbs.html) (also see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dbm)).

Most of the bucket schemes are based on [extensible hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extendible_hashing) with a special case for trying to store large keys or data that don't fit nicely into a bucket. [CiteSeer](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.127.4934) is also a good place to look for papers related to extensible hashing. (See the references of the linked paper, for example.)